# Isolate certain parts of a text file with shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
//unit-translator

#head
<

shell: /bin/bash;

>

#stuffs
<

[~]: ~;
[binary's]: /bin/bash;
[run-as-root]: sudo;


>

#commands
<

make-directory:mkdir;
move-to-directory:cd;
url-download-current-dirrectory:wget;
extract-here-tar:tar;
copy:cp;
remove-directory-+files:rm -R;
enter-root:su;

>
```

I want to isolate everything after "#commands", between the 2 "<", ">"'s as a string. How do I go about this?

I made the whole fille a string

```
translator=$(<config.txt)
```

I want to iscolate everything in the commands section, and store it as the variable "translator commands".

From that point I plan to split each line, and each set of commands something like this:

```
IFS=';' read -a translatorcommandlines <<< "$translatorcommands"
IFS=':' read -a translatorcommand <<< "$translatorcommandlines"
```

I'm so clueless, please help me!

Comment: please edit you Q to show your expected output given your sample data. Good luck.

Comment: Please, also try to explain better what you mean with *isolate*

Comment: A short `awk` script can do this, but first you're going to have to research `awk`.

Comment: Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins as you seem to be about to go down the wrong path.

Comment: ok ill look at awk! thanks x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to extract all lines after `#command` between `<` and `>` you can go with this command:

```
sed '0,/^#command/d' config.txt | sed '/>/q' | grep "^\w"
```

which skips all lines before `#command`, prints lines until `>` and takes only those starting with word character.

My output for your file is:

```
make-directory:mkdir;
move-to-directory:cd;
url-download-current-dirrectory:wget;
extract-here-tar:tar;
copy:cp;
remove-directory-+files:rm -R;
enter-root:su;
```

Answer (score 1):

The general purpose text processing tool for UNIX is "awk". You don't show in your question what you want your output to be so idk what you want but hopefully this is enough for you to figure it out from here:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=">"; FS="\n" }
{ gsub(/^.*<[[:blank:]]*\n|\n[[:blank:]]*$/,"") }
NF {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        print "record", NR, "field", i, "= [" $i "]"
    }
    print "----"
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
record 1 field 1 = []
record 1 field 2 = [shell: /bin/bash;]
record 1 field 3 = []
----
record 2 field 1 = []
record 2 field 2 = [[~]: ~;]
record 2 field 3 = [[binary's]: /bin/bash;]
record 2 field 4 = [[run-as-root]: sudo;]
record 2 field 5 = []
record 2 field 6 = []
----
record 3 field 1 = []
record 3 field 2 = [make-directory:mkdir;]
record 3 field 3 = [move-to-directory:cd;]
record 3 field 4 = [url-download-current-dirrectory:wget;]
record 3 field 5 = [extract-here-tar:tar;]
record 3 field 6 = [copy:cp;]
record 3 field 7 = [remove-directory-+files:rm -R;]
record 3 field 8 = [enter-root:su;]
record 3 field 9 = []
----
```